# SharePoint Online - This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS

Tags: office-365

I am trying to link to .js file from CDN, but it's telling me:

> This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS.

I am trying to link to this http://cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery.validation/1.14.0/additional-methods.min.js

I tried using https, and tried using // but didn't work.

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery.validation/1.14.0/additional-methods.min.js 

reference works for me.  What's 'not working', is no data coming back or is javascript not working?

Comment: This error message is showed when your site is running over HTTPS and you include scripts/files over HTTP. This should be fixed by including all scripts/files using HTTPS. But you mention that you still get the error. Could you give us some more information. Maybe screenshots. You are sure not another reference is causing the issue?

Comment: I am including the reference with //, so it should be adjusted automatically.

Comment: I get the same error, then change it to https and it works as usual. This was tested in Chrome on SP Online by reference the script in a script editor web part.

Comment: SPO doesn't translate protocol-less paths. Explicitly define HTTPS. There's no reason not to.

Comment: Put your JS on to Google drive and this link up with sharepoint

Answer (score 6):

Just replace `http` with `https`.

**Example**

Replace-

http://cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery.validation/1.14.0/additional-methods.min.js

with-

https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery.validation/1.14.0/additional-methods.min.js